# Prove that $A$ is a compact subset of $M_3(\Bbb R) \cong \Bbb R^9$.

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, lie-groups, compactness, topological-groups

Consider the set $A ⊂ M_3(\Bbb R)$ of $3 × 3$ real matrices with characteristic polynomial
$x^3 − 3x^2 + 2x − 1$.  Then $A$ is a compact subset of $M_3(\Bbb R) \cong \Bbb R^9$.

Now this polynomial is irreducible over rationals and it is equivalent to the companion matrix $$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    1& 0 & -2 \\
    0 & 1 & 3 \\
    \end{pmatrix}.
$$

Now am I missing any important theorems or details?

Comment: Could you please tell what metric you are using? The answer heavily depends on that.

Answer (score 2):

The statement is false. If $m\in\mathbb N$, then the characteristic polynomial of the matrix$$\begin{bmatrix}0&0&m\\\frac1{m^2}&0&-\frac2m\\0&m&3\end{bmatrix}$$is also $x^3-3x^2+2x-1$. Therefore, your set is unbounded. In particular, it is not compact.

Comment: Well, the 'bounded' part depends on the metric.

Comment: Sure. But it is clear that the metric here is $d\left((a_{ij})_{1\leqslant i,j\leqslant3},(b_{ij})_{1\leqslant i,j\leqslant3})\right)=\sqrt{\sum_{i,j=1}^3a_{i,j}^2}.$

Answer (score 0):

Let $B$ be your matrix and $V_t=\operatorname{diag}\{ t,1,1\}$.
Then $V_t B V_t^{-1}= \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & t \\
{1 \over t} & 0 & -2 \\ 0 & 1 & 3\end{bmatrix} \in A$ for all $t \neq 0$.